# VyOS: nat source rule [eth0] is not valid set failed

Tags: vyos

I have been getting "**nat source rule [eth0] is not valid set failed**" error on my vyos cli.
I have included my lab network diagram in this post as well.
i wanted to have the vyos as a router, and do the NAT. This setup done in Proxmox server, and i wanted to have a webserver on dmz and other devices on LAN to be able to connect to WAN.

Steps that i did for initial vyos setup:

```
---------- for eth0 (WAN) ------------- 

set interfaces ethernet eth0 address dhcp
set interfaces ethernet eth0 description 'WAN-INTERFACE'
```

```
---------- for eth1 (LAN) -------------
set interfaces ethernet eth1 address '192.168.1.1/24'
set interfaces ethernet eth1 description 'LAN-INTERFACE'

**for the nat- in the same console**
set nat source rule 100 source address '192.168.1.0/24'
set nat source rule 100 outbound-interface 'eth0'
set nat source rule 100 translation address masquerade

---------- for eth2 (DMZ) -------------
set interfaces ethernet eth2 address '192.168.2.1/29'
set interfaces ethernet eth2 description 'DMZ'


set nat source rule 200 source address '192.168.2.0/24'
set nat source rule 200 outbound-interface 'eth0'
set nat source rule 200 translation address masquerade
```

**Issue:**
But i have been getting the error that i mentioned above when setting the outbound-interface rule 'eth0' for both the eth1 or eth2.
by checking the 'show nat', i dont see the outbound-interface being implemented in the rules.

Steps i tried:
the only thing i knew and i did was to make sure the ethernet interface name is not something else other than eth0,  and indeed it is 'eth0'

How can i solve this??? Thank you in advance!!!!